# Replace empty result coming from JSON with value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am using the following script in Google Sheets to fetch a JSON object from Yahoo!Finance for certain companies:

```
function yahooFinance(symbol) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(symbol)
    + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
    + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
    + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
    ;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return [[
      quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.fmt,
      quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio.fmt,
      quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.marketCap.fmt
    ]];
  }
  else {
    return "-";
  }
}
```

Regularly, however, for one or more keys, the value will be emptyy. In such a case, the JSON returns   (an empty string). Whenever there is an empty string however, I would like to return a `-` back to the sheet to indicate that the query went fine, however no value was returned.

So I tried updating as follows (see the `if` statement):

```
function yahooFinance(symbol) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(symbol)
    + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
    + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
    + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
    ;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return [[
      (if (quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.fmtr) quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.dividendYield.fmt),
      quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.payoutRatio.fmt,
      quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail.marketCap.fmt
    ]];
  }
  else {
    return "-";
  }
}
```

Apparently, I cannot put an if-statement inside an array. How can I check each of the 3 values that I'm returning (`dividendYield`, `payoutRatio`, `marketCap`) if they are empty and if so, return `-`?

Comment: move your if-statement outside of the array. `if (condition){return "-"} return othervalue;`

Answer (score 3):

This is how i'd  do it. Additionally, it makes your code cleaner. The `||` works like a if/else. If the first value is defined, it will use that, if not, it will use the `"-"`

```
 function yahooFinance(symbol) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(symbol)
    + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
    + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
    + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
    ;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (responseCode === 200) {
    const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    const summaryDetail = quote.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail;
    const divYield = summaryDetail.dividendYield.fmt || "-";
    const payoutRatio = summaryDetail.payoutRatio.fmt || "-";
    const marketCap = summaryDetail.marketCap.fmt || "-";
    return [[ divYield , payoutRatio, marketCap ]];
  }
  else {
    return "-";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed only now that I sometimes can get an `#Error! TypeError: Cannot read property 'dividendYield' of undefined (line 41).` when a property is apparently not in te JSON. Is there a way to catch this too, and return a hyphen in such cases too?

Comment: @Pr0no just remove the `.fmt` from the variable declarations, and put it in the return statement instead. e.g `return [[divYield.fmt, ...]]`

Comment: I then get `#Error ReferenceError: fmt is not defined (line 45).` on every row.

Comment: The only way i can think of to fix that is to have a if statement for each that checks if each is undefined

Answer (score 2):

With [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.`, evaluation stops when a null-ish value is found. Think of using it this way:

```
potentially_nullish_thing?.prop_or_index_or_function
```

If the `potentially_nullish_thing` isn't null or undefined, the `prop_or_index_or_function` runs as you would expect. Otherwise, the whole expression evaluates to undefined.

So for the OP, pair that with the logical or `||` to get a default string if anything on the path to the real data is missing.

```
quote?.quoteSummary?.result?.[0]?.summaryDetail?.dividendYield?.fmt || '-',
// so on for the others
```

Comment: Whoa, learned something new, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! But I then get `Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'marketCap' of undefined (line 43).` Is there a way to return `-` whenever a property is not available for a certain object?

Comment: Does the line producing the error look like this?  `quote?.quoteSummary?.result?.[0]?.summaryDetail?.marketCap?.fmt || '-'` written that way, I don't see how it can produce that error.  If the expression up to `summaryDetail` is nullish, evaluation will stop with no error and the right side of the boolean `||` will evaluate.